# Can I still change to Java 13 as default once having installed Jenkins with Java 8?

Tags: jenkins

I have Java 13 installed and execute my tests in Eclipse using that version. I now want to install Jenkins for which Java 8 is a requirement. I installed Java 8 OpenJDK version using Homebrew on my Mac from cmd-line.

My query is: can I just change the default JAVA_HOME variable to Java 8 and install Jenkins and once installation is done, then revert back to Java 13 as default for other stuff? And later also change the JAVA_HOME variable to Java 8 as default and still use Jenkins safely?

Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Could someone please respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. After installing Jenkins, you can go to the folder of Jenkins and see that Jenkins has it's own JRE folder for java. That will be the default java executable that it uses. You can change it too for a specific java version on the `jenkins.xml`.

Comment: Thanks I will try!

Comment: I installed Java 8 and Jenkins and when I go to /Users/<myusername>/.jenkins I dont see any JRE folder or jenkins.xml. There is a config.xml but that has no mention of JRE. Could you inform how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: that's not the installed path. I'm not sure about mac but for centos it's in the `var/lib/jenkins`. you open jenkins after installing and check. `Manage Jenkins > System Information` and search for `JENKINS_HOME` and go to that path you'll find JRE there

Comment: Thanks! I was able to set up everything fine. I can change the environment vars in bash profile and also added JDK in Configure Tools in Jenkins. One useful observation: For Java 8 the path in cmd is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home and for Java 13 its /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home on Mac. Also to start/ stop Jenkins the sudo cmd should be pointing to homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist instead of org.jenkins-ci.plist. Thanks again!